# Data transfer between servers

Tags: networking, server

Assuming you have two bunch of servers, the first one dedicated to front and the other one, dedicated to process information from the fronts. What is the best way to transfer data from the fronts to the process servers;

I tried different techs on small amount of data:

- tried to dump data into files and retrieve them from the process servers... that's ok very secure because you never lose your data, but it uses a lot of disc write capacity.
- also tried sockets very cool

But sincerely I still don't know what is the best way to treat a huge data stream between servers.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What type of data? Google for "amqp" and then "RabbitMQ"

Comment: Take a look at message queues: AQ, MQ or any other variant. There are plenty of examples to be found. They offer some benefits like asynchronous transfer and reliability

Comment: Yes I used  one of the variant you mentioned: zeroMQ, I was pretty sure that was the good answer but i'am pretty newbie and I was not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the best option is to use a persistent queue, like RabbitMQ. That way if the receiving servers go down then your transfer is not lost and the transfer will simply continue when the receiving server pulls the data off the queue

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'll put more time into it.